# How do I convert xUnit/dotnet test output to annotations in GitHub actions using a problem matcher?

Tags: .net, yaml, github-actions, mstest, xunit

I have a GitHub action that runs .NET xUnit tests using `dotnet test`:

```yaml
jobs:
  build-net:
    name: .NET build & test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 7.0.100      
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build
```

The testing step outputs something like this for each test:

```
  Failed Library.Tests.UnitTest1.DeliberateFail2 [< 1 ms]
  Error Message:
   System.Exception : Error message
  Stack Trace:
     at Library.Tests.UnitTest1.DeliberateFail2() in /home/runner/work/Library/Library.Tests/UnitTest1.cs:line 30
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
```

And then a summary:

```
Failed!  - Failed:     2, Passed:   133, Skipped:     0, Total:   135, Duration: 639 ms - Library.Tests.dll (net7.0)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This results in a single step failed message in the action:

[image: screenshot of the GitHub action output]

As you can see the null reference warning from `dotnet build` points to a line of code (and will appear next to that line in a PR) while `dotnet test` just gives me `Process completed with exit code 1`

I don't just want a failed build step, I want an *annotation* for each failed test.

There are existing ways to fix this:

- With a new dependency and output handler: https://github.com/Tyrrrz/GitHubActionsTestLogger
- With a custom action that publishes the test output back to the repo as markdown: https://github.com/EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action
- With a custom action that parses `.trx` results into `.md` format https://github.com/dorny/test-reporter

But they all involve changes to my action pipeline or a new dependency, *neither of which I want*.

According to GitHub's documentation I *should* be able to fix this with a [problem matcher](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/docs/problem-matchers.md), a regex that converts the `dotnet test` output into the annotation format (similar to the same pattern in VSCode).

The regex to parse the `dotnet test` output looks like [`^\s*Failed\s(.*)([\s\S]*?)(Stack\sTrace:\s*at\s)(.*)\s+in\s+(.*):line\s+(\d+)\s*$`](https://regex101.com/r/rNeli2/1) and I add it as `.github/xunit.json`:

```json
{
  "problemMatcher": [
    {
      "owner": "xunit",
      "pattern": [ 
        {
          "regexp": "^\\s*Failed\\s(.*)([\\s\\S]*?)(Stack\\sTrace:\\s*at\\s)(.*)\\s+in\\s+(.*):line\\s+(\\d+)\\s*$",
          "file": 5,
          "fromPath": 5,
          "line": 6,
          "message": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then I use `add-matcher` to include this:

```yaml
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore
    - name: set matcher
      run: echo "::add-matcher::${{ github.workspace }}/.github/xunit.json"
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-build --logger "trx;LogFileName=test-results.trx"
```

That doesn't work - I still don't get annotations.

I've also tried multi-line problem matching:

```json
{
  "problemMatcher": [
    {
      "owner": "xunit",
      "pattern": [ 
        {
          "regexp": "^\\s*Failed\\s(.*)$",
          "message": 1
        },
        {
          "regexp": "^\\s*at\\s(.*)\\s+in\\s+(.*):line\\s+(\\d+)\\s*$",
          "file": 2,
          "fromPath": 2,
          "line": 3,
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Has anyone already built a GitHub problem matcher for `dotnet test` output? It seems crazy nobody else has already done this?

Can anyone help fix these regexes (or point out what I'm doing wrong configuring the action)?

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action?

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for - we already use `actions/upload-artifact@v3` to save the results. What I want is to turn the failing tests (which some as single message) into formatted messages in GitHub that relate to the failing line in the repository. `actions/setup-dotnet@v3` already sets up a problem matched for compilation errors, I just need the equivalent for xUnit output.

Comment: publish-unit-test-result-action [seems to do that](https://github.com/EnricoMi/publish-unit-test-result-action?tab=readme-ov-file#commit-and-pull-request-annotations), no?

Comment: @BenjaminW. that's the result I want, but _without_ adding a new publish pipeline. It should be possible with a JSON problem matcher file, but that project is doing it with a Python script. I want to know how to do this, not switch to a new process that does this amongst a bunch of other steps.

Comment: Tested your scenario and it does generate annotations. See a test [run](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/6259159443) and [workflow](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/6259159443/workflow). With valid files paths, it should generate the complete annotations. Observe the debug logs [here](https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/6259159443/job/16994600048#step:3:22). However, the exceptions are multiline and may not always contain the same number of lines. I'm not sure how you would handle that. For above test, I stripped down the logs to the required lines only.

Comment: @Azeem thanks, that minimum repo is really helpful. I think it's the multiline logs that're the problem - they can be any number of lines depending on the test failure message. With regard to the paths - they all have the `/home/runner/work/` prefix but that's just where `actions/checkout@v3` puts them by default - do I need to strip those out somehow?

Comment: @Keith: You're welcome! Yes, those variable number of intermediate lines are the real issue here. Regarding path prefixes, I don't see any issues them. Anyone can easily track them down in the repo.

Comment: @Azeem I think something should be possible with `loop` (like [this](https://github.com/KeithHenry/test-actions/blob/7d5b5e5318e653b9f41ce4b291b78f8a9d42b7e8/.github/workflows/xunit-test.yml#L17-L37), though it doesn't work) but I'm not sure how to stop that (even if it worked) creating an annotation per line instead of per test

Comment: @Keith: I already tried that. The `loop` option is only valid for the last pattern of the multiline matcher. Apparently, the problem matcher solution doesn't scale for multiple errors due to its [limitations](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/docs/problem-matchers.md#limitations) and for the lack of configuration options. IMO, after dumping test logs to a file and then scanning those for your required output makes more sense here.

Answer (score 3):

Tested your scenario and it does generate annotations.

Here's a test workflow and its output:

```yaml
name: problem_matcher_test

on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  ci:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Add problem matcher
      env:
        PROBLEM_MATCHER_CONFIG: |
          {
            "problemMatcher": [
              {
                "owner": "xunit",
                "pattern": [
                  {
                    "regexp": "^\\s*Failed\\s(.*)$",
                    "message": 1
                  },
                  {
                    "regexp": "^\\s*at\\s(.*)\\s+in\\s+(.*):line\\s+(\\d+)\\s*$",
                    "file": 2,
                    "fromPath": 2,
                    "line": 3
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
      run: |
        echo "$PROBLEM_MATCHER_CONFIG" > xunit.json
        echo "$PWD/xunit.json"
        cat -n "$PWD/xunit.json"
        echo "::add-matcher::$PWD/xunit.json"

    - name: Dumping Logs
      env:
        LOGS: |
          Failed Library.Tests.UnitTest1.DeliberateFail1 [< 1 ms]
            at Library.Tests.UnitTest1.DeliberateFail1() in /home/runner/work/Library/Library.Tests/UnitTests.cs:line 1
          Failed Library.Tests.UnitTest1.DeliberateFail2 [< 1 ms]
            at Library.Tests.UnitTest1.DeliberateFail2() in /home/runner/work/Library/Library.Tests/UnitTests.cs:line 2
      run: |
        echo "$LOGS"

    - name: Remove problem matcher
      run: |
        echo "::remove-matcher::$PWD/xunit.json"
```

Output:

[image: annotations]

With valid files paths, it should generate the complete annotations. Observe these debug logs here about paths:

[image: paths]

However, the exceptions are multiline and may not always contain the same number of lines. For above test, I stripped down the logs to the required lines only.

---

Apparently, the problem matcher solution doesn't scale for multiple multiline errors due to its [limitations](https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/main/docs/problem-matchers.md#limitations) and for the lack of configuration options.

IMO, after dumping test logs to a file and then scanning those for your required output makes more sense here if you don't want to go with an existing solution.

Comment: Thanks, but that example works because it takes out the problem lines. The messages from .NET can be multiline and there's no options you can pass to `dotnet test` that stop that (you can turn off per-test logs and just show totals, but that's it). Like the example in the question, not just the first and fifth lines.

Comment: @Keith: As already discussed, it's the limitation of the pattern matcher itself. Regardless of the number of lines, it works. If you want to make it work then I have suggested the scanning of the log file as well. Apart from that, to make pattern matcher work with the separate file solution, you can remove the newlines from that file and your first regex should work too (after dumping the new transformed file in the logs). But, in any case, there's some intermediate processing involved.

Comment: Yeah, that rather suggests the answer is actually that this is impossible. You can get problem matcher annotations to work, but _only_ if you edit the output from `dotnet test` first, which does rather defeat the point. If I add a realistic multi-line log (as [here](https://github.com/KeithHenry/test-actions/blob/d9ec1586bc4b56da7f2db0231a55d4826cd09e75/.github/workflows/xunit-test.yml#L43-L49)) those [multiline logs don't annotate](https://github.com/KeithHenry/test-actions/actions/runs/6325707363)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to work around the limitations with multi-line matching,<sup>*</sup> so this is my problem matcher:

```
PROBLEM_MATCHER_CONFIG: |
  {
    "problemMatcher": [
      {
        "owner": "xunit",
        "pattern": [
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*Failed\\s(.*)$"
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*Error Message:\\s*$"
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*(.*?)\\s*$",
            "message": 1
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*Expected:"
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*Actual:"
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*Stack Trace:\\s*$"
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*at\\s(.*)\\s+in\\s+(.*):line\\s+(\\d+)\\s*$",
            "file": 2,
            "fromPath": 2,
            "line": 3
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "owner": "xunit.exc",
        "pattern": [
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*Failed\\s(.*)$"
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*Error Message:\\s*$"
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*(.*Exception.*)\\s*$",
            "message": 1
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*Stack Trace:\\s*$"
          },
          {
            "regexp": "^\\s*at\\s(.*)\\s+in\\s+(.*):line\\s+(\\d+)\\s*$",
            "file": 2,
            "fromPath": 2,
            "line": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

It was necessary to define 2 owners to get the different output formats matched. The first one matches the regular dotnet test case output where an expected result differs. E.g. like here:

```
  Failed Prime.UnitTests.Services.PrimeService_IsPrimeShould.IsPrime_InputIs2_ReturnTrue [2 ms]
  Error Message:
   2 should be prime
  Expected: True
  Actual:   False
  Stack Trace:
     at Prime.Services.PrimeService.IsPrime(Int32 candidate) in C:\Users\Jens\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\unit-testing-using-dotnet-test\PrimeService\PrimeService.cs:line 9
   at Prime.UnitTests.Services.PrimeService_IsPrimeShould.IsPrime_InputIs1_ReturnFalse() in C:\Users\Jens\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\unit-testing-using-dotnet-test\PrimeService.Tests\PrimeService_IsPrimeShould.cs:line 12
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
```

The second one matches the output from test cases that throw an exception, like here:

```
  Failed Prime.UnitTests.Services.PrimeService_IsPrimeShould.IsPrime_InputIs1_ReturnFalse [2 ms]
  Error Message:
   System.NotImplementedException : Not implemented.
  Stack Trace:
     at Prime.Services.PrimeService.IsPrime(Int32 candidate) in C:\Users\Jens\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\unit-testing-using-dotnet-test\PrimeService\PrimeService.cs:line 10
   at Prime.UnitTests.Services.PrimeService_IsPrimeShould.IsPrime_InputIs1_ReturnFalse() in C:\Users\Jens\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\unit-testing-using-dotnet-test\PrimeService.Tests\PrimeService_IsPrimeShould.cs:line 12
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
```

This will lead to valid annotations for both kinds of dotnet test outcome, at least for standard test cases where actual/expected/exception text fit onto single lines.

[image]

---

<sup>*</sup> Regarding multiline problem matching see also this [VSCode open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9635).